# jQuery explanation of (!= and == and others)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery and I have seen that people in plugins use following quite a lot, and I don't know the meaning of each. So explanation of each would be really appreciated.

So here's the list, maybe I have type wrong some of but anyone is welcome to edit my post.

```
==, ===, !0, !1, !=, !==
```

Please explain to me... Thanks!

Comment: Sorry raina77 might be my bad :)
I'll remove that !===

Comment: I won't downvote Norla's one, but I really think that it's far more beneficial using [MDN repository](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) of JS knowledge instead - especially for [this specific case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: These are not specific to jQuery,  they are operators in JavaScript language. JQUERY is a library built on top of JavaScript.

Comment: @BuddhiP thanks for that information. I thought it's only for jQuery :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this list of javascript logical operators:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

and comparison operators:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Oh yes... Theres these && too thanks :) 
Too many!

Answer (score 5):

```
Operator    Description  
==          is equal to      
===         is exactly equal to (value and type)      
!=          is not equal     
!==         is not equal (neither value nor type)     
>           is greater than x>8  
<           is less than    x<8  
>=          is greater than or equal to  
<=          is less than or equal to
!0              Not 0 (could be used as not false)
!1              Not 1 (could be used as not true)
```

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Comparison operators
var foo = 1;
var bar = 0;
var baz = "1";
var bim = 2;

foo == bar;   // returns false
foo != bar;   // returns true
foo == baz;   // returns true; but note that the types are different

foo === baz;             // returns false
foo !== baz;             // returns true
foo === parseInt( baz );   // returns true

foo > bim;    // returns false
bim > baz;    // returns true
foo <= baz;   // returns true
```

Link: http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/operators/

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, these are used to compare 2 values in an "if" statement. They are called comparison operators. Each one makes a different comparison. The most confusing are the 2= and the 3=. The third equals sign compares data types as well as value. More often than not, you will not need the 3rd = sign unless you are creating "strict" code. The operators break down like so:

- **==** is equal to

  - *Example*: if (x == z) // this would return true if both x and z were the number 7
- **===** is exactly equal to (compares value and type)

  - *Example*: if (x == z) // if x is the String 7 and z is the Integer 7, this would return false
- **!=** is not equal

  - *Example*: if (x != z) // if x is 7 and z is 8 then this if statement would return true
- **!==** is not equal (again, compares both value and type)

  - *Example*: if (x !== z) // If both x and z are 7 but one is a String, while the other is an integer, then this would return true, because they are not the same type
- **>** is greater than

  - *Example*: if (x > z) // If x is 8 and z is 7, then this would return true
- **<** is less than

  - *Example*: if (x < z) // If x is 8 and z is 7, then this would return false
- **>=** is greater than or equal to

  - *Example*: if (x >= z) // If x is 8 or 7 and z is 7, then this would still be true in either case
- **<=** is less than or equal to

  - *Example*: if (x <= z) // If x is 8 and z is 7, then this would return false, but if x was 7 then it would be true

For more information, please follow these links:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/comparison_operators.shtml
- http://www.how-to-code.com/javascript/javascript-tutorial/comparison-operators-in-javascript.html